# Fill word Content Control using C# issue

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have word contains content control like

[image]

I want to write many lines on it so in C# I tried many ways :

1. using EnviromentNewLine .
2. \n
3. 

Example:

```
                for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
                {
                    items[i] = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", (i + 1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), ". ", items[i], "<br />"); 
                }
```

but I still get the word content control on one line , any idea how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is, that the plain text content control does not support multiple *paragraphs*, it is only possibly to insert manual line breaks (which you normally do by pressing Shift+Return). Within the plain text content control, Word automatically replaces Return by Shift+Return as you can see when switching on the formatting symbols.

You basically have two options to solve your issue:

- Change the content control to a rich text content control. That way you will be able to insert arbitrary content, also new line characters (i.e. multiple actual Word paragraphs)
- Insert a *vertical tab*, i.e. ASCII character 11 or `\B` instead of a new line. This will insert the manual line break required by the plain text content control.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\r
```

[MSDN 2.4.4.4 Character literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx)